# Jpql query to extract array value

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

My database contain a column which is the type of varchar.

In that column i am storing value in the form [1,2] .
I need to get first value '1'.
I need to write jpql query using @query of spring data jpa.

I have decided to remove the braces of the value by using substring function then i need to convert it to array.

So, I have tried like this for the substring extraction.

```
  SUBSTRING(u.output,1,LENGTH(u.output-2))
```

Is this syntax correct for substring extraction? how convert it to array.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot normalise the database then I would normalise the domain model via a JPA Converter.

You can these just load the entity and navigate the array as normal.

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters

```
@Entity
public MyEntity{
    @Convert(converter = MyArrayConverter.class)
    int [] values;
}
```

Create a JPA Converter:

```
@Converter
public class MyArrayConverter implements
  AttributeConverter<Integer [], String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(int [] values) {
      //convert int [] to string "[1,2,3]"
    }

    @Override
    public Integer [] convertToEntityAttribute(String dbValue) {
      //convert string "[1,2,3]" to int []
    }
}
```

Comment: In that column i am storing different types of values like json string also, If i use coverter it will applicable to another types of values. I dont need that.

Comment: Sound lovely. Hopefully this is some legacy code and not something you are developing from scratch!